# how to get customfield attributes in MS Project

Tags: c#, vba, vb.net, office-interop, ms-project

I have been working on MS Project comaddin

```
w_itemVal =  g_projAppObj.CustomFieldValueListGetItem(a_TextFieldId, MSProject.PjValueListItem.pjValueListValue, cnt)
```

this is how I get values from lookup table of text type custom field
but it gives error when there are no lookup values are present
hence I am not able to make difference between Dropdown (with no lookup values) & simple text Field

**thus I wanted to know how to get customfield attributes in MS Project c# or vb.net com-addin**

[image]

My addin is compatible with MS Project 2013 & 2016

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know how to get customfield attributes in MS Project

### Bottom line

While the custom field attribute can be ***set*** via the object model, it can't be read.

### Details

This is an example of how the API is lacking.

You can get the list of values defined for a custom lookup field using [CustomFieldValueListGetItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.customfieldvaluelistgetitem). But if there are no values it is not determinable if the attribute is set to Lookup (with no values) or None.

Note: the [CustomFieldValueListAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.customfieldvaluelistadd) method does not fail if the field custom attribute is set to None, so it cannot be used deduce the attribute setting.

Comment: thanks for response, my basic purpose is to get to know if there is change in attribute type like from none to lookup or vice a versa , so any event or something else just to read its attribute type none. if not in Dot net then there is macro window available so in macro window there might be be some thing to read attribute type